# Burninate the [apple] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

It has already been established that [the [apple] tag should be burned to death](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199189/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags).

A bunch of questions havee been cleaned up and now there are currently [only two questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bapple%5d%20-%5bcocoa%5d%20%20-%5bios%5d%20-%5biphone%5d%20-%5bosx*%5d%20%20-%5bapp-store%5d%20-%5bxcode%5d%20-%5bapplescript%5d%20-%5bicloud%5d%20-%5bitunes%5d%20-%5bipad%5d%20-%5bobjective-c%5d%20-%5bsafari%5d%20-%5bitunesconnect%5d%20closed%3ano) without other relevent apple-related tags.

Please destroy this tag.

Comment: Meh, wouldn't it be better just to add [meta-tag:burniate-request] to that question you linked?

Comment: +1 for H*R/Trogdor reference.